# Why is AWS lambda function getting NullReferenceException in C# API?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a .Net 6 API which is deployed on AWS lambda. In theory everything is set up right, but when I try to call the API from postman, it giver "internal server error".

The problem is a NullReferenceException.

```
2022-12-23T19:59:07.791Z    9b343352-fd3f-4c34-a1a5-3f46251b7f1e    fail    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)

at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)

at lambda_method2(Closure , Stream , ILambdaContext , Stream )

at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeLoader.Invoke(Stream lambdaData, ILambdaContext lambdaContext, Stream outStream) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs:line 145

at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.HandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetHandlerWrapper>b__0(InvocationRequest invocation) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/HandlerWrapper.cs:line 56

at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InvokeOnceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/LambdaBootstrap.cs:line 176
```

I call the FunctionHandlerAsync in AWS, which I read is the correct function, I followed many tutorials on how to set it up, but even if I did it in the same way, just doesn't work.

Lambda entrypoint:

```
namespace API
{
    public class LambdaFunction : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
    {
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            try
            {
                builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).UseStartup<Startup>().UseLambdaServer();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although the request passes, I also get some error when I try to test the API in the lambda test with

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "headers": {},
  "multiValueHeaders": {
    "Content-Type": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "body": "",
  "isBase64Encoded": false
```

I am new to this cloud world and I would really need some solution to this, I am working on it for 3 days and literally the deployment generates me a way bigger headache than the actual creation of the API.

Comment: `AspNetCoreServer`? Can you please show us your using statements? Which Nuget packages do you have configured? What is your request?

Comment: Yes, `AspNetCoreServer` is the package. No other using statements in that class, but I post the packages included:
 <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents" Version="2.5.0" />

<PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer" Version="6.1.0" />

<PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="2.1.0" />

<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.7.102.3" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.11">

I also tried both GET and POST requests, non of them are working

Comment: 404 suggests you're not calling it correctly - how are you calling it? What's your request?

Comment: I run the lambda test, default API Gateway Proxy test, when I get the 404. When I call it from Postman, Get or Post, I get internal server error 500.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out?  Hitting the same problem.

Comment: Are you passing a payload to your API method?

Comment: Don’t wrap your inner exception. You are loosing stack information

Answer (score 0):

My problem for me was function-handler in the aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file that was not correct because the function that I was trying to deploy was not existing (cause of the NullReferenceException). So just make sure that the path to it is correct.